# Probability of variable importance calculation error in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, random-forest

I am trying to calculate the probability of variable importance each bands for classification. Basically, I have 3 class but when I try to implement the probability of variable importance, the error statement is "Expected 2 classes for PROBABILITY, found 3". Could you please inform the problem in the code?

```
var geometry = ee.FeatureCollection("users/seneralkan77/water_4326");
Map.addLayer(geometry)
var aquatic = /* color: #ff0000 */ee.FeatureCollection(
        [ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-11.15696644,7.00857888]),
            {
              "watercover": 0,
              "system:index": "0"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-11.18116639,6.99607471]),
            {
              "watercover": 0,
              "system:index": "1"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-11.19274503,6.98715114]),
            {
              "watercover": 0,
              "system:index": "2"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-11.15285584 , 6.9951071]),
            {
              "watercover": 0,
              "system:index": "3"
            })]),
    fish_middle_class = /* color: #3b8b00 */ee.FeatureCollection(
        [ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-11.17854238,6.99824484]),
            {
              "watercover": 1,
              "system:index": "4"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-11.15719553,7.00526697]),
            {
              "watercover": 1,
              "system:index": "5"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-11.15692738,7.00521914]),
            {
              "watercover": 1,
              "system:index": "6"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-11.15856715,7.00432886]),
            {
              "watercover": 1,
              "system:index": "7"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-11.1668752,7.00175725]),
            {
              "watercover": 1,
              "system:index": "8"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-11.15510189,7.00024551]),
            {
              "watercover": 1,
              "system:index": "9"
            })]),
    fish_low_class = /* color: #0300ff */ee.FeatureCollection(
        [ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-11.15520286,7.00077292]),
            {
              "watercover": 2,
              "system:index": "10"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-11.14973369,6.9887299]),
            {
              "watercover": 2,
              "system:index": "11"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-11.14880352,6.98930031]),
            {
              "watercover": 2,
              "system:index": "12"
            })]);


// Load the Sentinel-2
var sentinel2018 = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2/20180104T110431_20180104T111712_T29NKH')

// Merge the three geometry layers into a single FeatureCollection.
var newfc = aquatic.merge(fish_middle_class).merge(fish_low_class);

// Use these bands for classification.
var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12'];
// The name of the property on the points storing the class label.
var classProperty = 'watercover'

// Sample the composite to generate training data.  Note that the
// class label is stored in the 'watercover' property.
var training = sentinel2018.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: newfc,
  properties: [classProperty],
  scale: 30
});

// Train a RF classifier.
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10).setOutputMode('PROBABILITY').train(training,"watercover",bands);
// Print some info about the classifier (specific to RF).
//print('Random Forest, explained', classifier.explain());

var dict = classifier.explain();
print('Explain:',dict);

var variable_importance = ee.Feature(null, ee.Dictionary(dict).get('importance'));

var chart =
  ui.Chart.feature.byProperty(variable_importance)
    .setChartType('ColumnChart')
    .setOptions({
      title: 'Random Forest Variable Importance',
      legend: {position: 'none'},
      hAxis: {title: 'Bands'},
      vAxis: {title: 'Importance'}
    });


print(chart);
```

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled over the same problem and finally found out that in the description of the `ee.Classifier.mode()` another option is listed: `MULTIPROBABILITY`. Used this and it seemed to work, at least I was able to create the feature importances by adjusting my script to the example from [Results of Variable Importance of RF Classifier in GEE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366165/results-of-variable-importance-of-rf-classifier-in-gee).

Assuming an image called `MYIMAGE` with `all_bands` and some `training_areas` with a class attribute `CLASSNUM`, it looks like this:

```
var all_bands = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6', 'b7', 'b8'];
var training_data = MYIMAGE.select(all_bands).sampleRegions({
    collection: training_areas,
    properties: ['CLASSNUM'],
    scale: 2
});
// Get probabilities
var probabilities = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest({
    numberOfTrees: 10,
    variablesPerSplit: 2,
    seed: 42
}).setOutputMode('MULTIPROBABILITY').train({
    features: training_data,
    classProperty: 'CLASSNUM',
    inputProperties: all_bands
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The docs state:

> Not all classifier types support `REGRESSION` and `PROBABILITY` modes.

If you try your code with only two classes, it works. It must mean that `ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest()` only support `PROBABILITY` output mode when you have two classes, which pretty much is what the error message suggested.